# publish or export a ADF task flow diagram to external document -- possibly in PDF format

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

JDeveloper 12c permits viewing ADF task flows as diagram. Is it possible to export the diagram part to an external file--pdf or png?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, because taksflow diagram is just a xml file, and it is interpreted by jdev in proper way to visualize to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 10, you can probably use the Print Functionality.

From File Menu > Print (or Print Preview) and Select "Microsoft Print to PDF", attached screenshot displayed below:

[image: Print Dialog in JDeveloper 12c]